# How do I write an eloquent query which joins, merges or unions these 2 queries into 1?

Tags: php, laravel

// 2 eloqent collections merged

```
$publicCategories = Category::where('menu', '=', 1)
    ->where('display_scope', 1)
    ->orderBy('parent_id')
    ->get();
$privateCategories = Category::where('menu', '=', 1)
    ->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->orderBy('parent_id')
    ->get();
$categories = $publicCategories->merge($privateCategories);
```

// This query above does these 2 MySQL queries which are duplicated.

[image]

The result from this is correct, however, requires 2 queries.
How do I write an eloquent query which joins, merges or unions these 2 queries into 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you're getting it separately? You can use `Orwhere` for this.

```
$publicprivateCategories = Category::where('menu', '=', 1)
                        ->whereIn('id', $ids)
                        ->orWhere('display_scope', 1)
                        ->orderBy('parent_id')
                        ->get();
```

**Update**

```
$publicprivateCategories = Category::where('menu', '=', 1)
                        ->where(function($q) use($ids){
                             $q->whereIn('id', $ids)->orWhere('display_scope', 1);
                        })
                        ->where('id', '!=', 2)
                        ->orderBy('parent_id')
                        ->get();
```

By this, you'll get both(Public or private) categories.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: This answer is correct. On top of this, I recommend you to have a look into `Query Optimisation` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015685/5326191

Comment: Very helpful for `Query Optimisation` I appreciated.

Comment: I had to add ->where('id', '!=', 2). Because the previous query is 2 separate queries. How do I do a subquery with eloquent?

Comment: Check Update for that.