# How to optimize mysql query with union of two tables having more than 750,000 records in both tables?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, union, sql-optimization

I have two tables `propeties_1` and `properties_2`.
Table `propeties_1` has 350,000 records and Table `propeties_2` has 400,000 records.

I am using query as following:

```
Select union_table.* FROM
(
    (select col1 as c1, col2 as c2, col3 as c3 from `propeties_1` where status='A')
    union
    (select colm1 as c1, colm2 as c2, colm3 as c3 from `propeties_2` where status='A')
) as union_table 
limit 12 offset 0 order by c1;
```

This query takes too much time in execution.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: How many rows do you expect in the result, from each table

Comment: @Nick 13, but who's counting ;-)

Comment: @HarpalSingh Please test all code before posting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I need 12 records at a time but, results should be from union of tables

Comment: @HarpalSingh There are multiple factors that play under optimization. I recommend going through this link for better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015018/laravel-use-mysql-indexing/60015685#60015685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly optimize your query if you have `propeties_1.status` and `propeties_2.status` marked as [`INDEX`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) on database.

You can easily create it with the following instructions:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_status1 on propeties_1(status);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_status2 on propeties_2(status);
```

Indexes are special lookup tables that the database search engine can use to speed up data retrieval. Simply put, an index is a pointer to data in a table. An index in a database is very similar to an index in the back of a book.

Comment: Have you tried using [`UNION ALL`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm) Clause?

Comment: I doubt seriously if `status` is `UNIQUE`??

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple trick -- add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to the inner queries.  More discussion here, including what to do with `OFFSET`:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union

And have these composite indexes:

```
propeties_1:  INDEX(status, col1)
propeties_2:  INDEX(status, colm1)
```