# Laravel Task scheduling consume 60% of cpu

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Laravel scheduler that loop over some configuration and call artisan commands.

What I noticed that every time the scheduler starts, it consumes 60% of CPU and same for commands started from the scheduler, starts with high CPU and ends with 1.5% of the CPU.

Any clue what could result in such behaviour?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out? I'm having a similar issue... Turns out that in my development environmente (Homestead, so nginx) this isn't an issue but on production (a cloud-based Windows Server VM), CPU usage skyrockets.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about CPU consumption, I'm guessing optmization could be a reason.

1) Let's first try it with [php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) `memory_get_usage`. Since you are using [Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling), I recommend adding the below block of code where needed and **Log** them step by step to see memory usage.

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

echo convert(memory_get_usage(true)); // 123 kb
Log::debug('memory usage');
?>
```

You can access the logs under /storage/logs folder. At least you will get and idea where you memory is consumed unnecessarily.

2) Next, you can go through these [6 steps of optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015018/laravel-use-mysql-indexing/60015685#60015685) elaborated in this stack overflow question.

3) How often the scheduler is running? Maybe you can increase the interval.

4) When do you run it? If you are running it when the portal is swamped by users, then try changing the time to later/before stage where the server is not used by users.

**Lastly**, I can say that most of the time it's because of bad coding. **Refactor** so you can re-use code. **Optimize** so you use what is needed.
Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: So far I run it every minute. the tricky part that even if the code just sleep for 5 seconds and return for debugging, it still begin with 60% and goes down to 0%

Comment: Is it a shared hosting? Or are you running on local?

Comment: it happens both remotely as well as on local docker image

Comment: Did you get a chance to check memory usage?

Comment: yeah memory usage is stable 0.6% and always stays like that, I doubt that Laravel bootstrap the whole application when running artisan commands