# Laravel best practice method for querying using an index key in table

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following database table:

```
id     - PK (Auto Increment)
hash   - a unique index the value here is filled using the function "uniqid()"  
title  - string..
```

I want to query from table using a hash value not the id. Is this practice will load the server, as I know is the best way to get some row from the database table especially the one who contain high number of rows is searching using a primary key:

```
$row = Book::find(1);
```

Or I can use the following eloquent builder without worry of making unnecessary load to database server because he hash is set as a unique key:

```
$row = Book::where('hash',$hashFromAPiRequest)->first();
```

There is a package named [laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scout), I am not sure if I really need to use it or not.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Laravel.  Assuming, MySQL, the fastest way is by key, as InnoDB implements a clustered index by PK.  With that said, access by the indexed hash is highly efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Laravel Scout for this. A simple where condition will suffice. As long as the hash column is **indexed**, your query will not load up the server.

However, since you mentioned unnecessary load, you can still **optimized** a tiny bit here by using **select()**. Please use only those columns that you really need otherwise you are sending/consuming additional bytes of data.

```
$row = Book::select('id', 'title')->where('hash',$hashFromAPiRequest)->first();
```

You can also check out [Laravel use mysql indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015018/laravel-use-mysql-indexing/60015685#60015685) if you want to learn more about optimizing.