# Laravel Best way to improve performance searching in a big collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables :

- ads (id, name, type_id ,city_id)
- types (id, slug, name)
- cities (id, slug, name) (37000 entries)
- states (id, slug, name) (120 entries)

I can have a url like this :
https://example.com/ad,type,city.html
or like this :
https://example.com/ad,type,state.html

I need to do a search ads filter by slugs and i'm doing like this to get my ads filtered :

```
$slugs = explode(',', $slugs);
$ads = Ad::where('is_active', true)->get();

foreach ($slug as slug){

    $types = Type::all();
    if ($types->contains('slug', $slug)) {
        $type = $types->first(function ($value) use ($slug) {
        return $value->slug == $slug;
    });

    $ads = $ads->where('type_id', $type->id);

    $cities = City::all();
    if ($cities->contains('slug', $slug)) {
        $city = $cities->first(function ($value) use ($slug) {
        return $city->slug == $slug;
    });

    $ads = $ads->where('city_id', $city->id);

    $states = State::all();
    if ($states->contains('slug', $slug)) {
        $state = $states->first(function ($value) use ($slug) {
        return $state->slug == $slug;
    });

    $ads = $ads->where('state_id', $state->id);

}

return $ads;
}
```

This works. 
But as i have many cities it can be slow (between 1 and 2 seconds). 
How can i improve this ? 
I was thinking to use cache like memcached to put cities on it, but the result doesn't change so much. Maybe is the way i builded it who is wrong ?

Comment: You are not "properly" querying on cities and states - you are getting all these rows(37K is huge for this) and filtering after it on application layer, instead of data layer. You are querying in a for loop too, that's also another performance problem. query with `whereIn` those slugs.

Comment: First: look that you're querying `::all()` in each iteration of loop. Move $types, $cities and $states outside of foreach.

Comment: You should delegate the query to the database instead using collections

Comment: Or better yet, create one query. WhereHas May come handy.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for you advises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Loops**: Your `Type`, `City` & `State` modals are not gonna change for each loop. It's better to query them before that.

```
$types = Type::all();
$cities = City::all();
$states = State::all();

foreach ($slug as slug) {
```

2) **Cache**: Caching for these three modals seems appropriate.

3) Since I don't want to repeat, please go through this thread on [how to optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015685/5326191). It talks about proper use of **select()**, **Indexing**, **data types** and some more.

Keep me posted in the comments below. Cheers!

Comment: thanks a lot mate. Sounds evident about the 1, i don't know why i didn't see this when i wrote it.

Comment: Bonus. For the cache i configured Redis and did like this :
$cities = Cache::get('cities', function () {
            return DB::table('cities')->get();
        });
i save a lot of time !